# Ошибка при установке ssl сертификата -"ssl_stapling" ignored

Tags: nginx, centos, ssl, openssl, centos6

Использую связку Apache|+Nginx

Получаю следующую ошибку после команды nginx -t

```
nginx: [warn] "ssl_stapling" ignored, issuer certificate not found for certificate "/etc/nginx/ssl/emrdeveloper.ru.pem"
nginx: [warn] "ssl_stapling" ignored, issuer certificate not found for certificate "/etc/nginx/ssl/tracex.emrdeveloper.ru.pem"
nginx: the configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf syntax is ok
nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test is successful
```

Делал все по [этому](https://kamaok.org.ua/?p=664) примеру.

вот мой ssl.conf

```
ssl_session_timeout 1d;
ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
#ssl_ciphers ECDH+AESGCM:DH+AESGCM:ECDH+AES256:DH+AES256:ECDH+AES128:DH+AES:ECDH+3DES:DH+3DES:RSA+AESGCM:RSA+AES:RSA+3DES:!aNULL:!MD5:!DSS;
ssl_ciphers 'EECDH+AESGCM:EDH+AESGCM:AES256+EECDH:AES256+EDH';
ssl_dhparam /etc/nginx/ssl/dhparam.pem;
# ssl_ecdh_curve secp521r1;

## Improves TTFB by using a smaller SSL buffer than the nginx default
ssl_buffer_size 8k;

## Enables OCSP stapling
ssl_stapling on;
resolver **ТУТ IP СЕРВЕРА**
ssl_stapling_verify on;

## Send header to tell the browser to prefer https to http traffic
#add_header Strict-Transport-Security max-age=31536000;
```

вот конфиг nginx

```
server {
 listen 80;
 listen     443 ssl;
 server_name   emrdeveloper.ru www.emrdeveloper.ru;
 ssl_certificate         /etc/nginx/ssl/emrdeveloper.ru.pem;
 ssl_certificate_key     /etc/nginx/ssl/emrdeveloper.ru.key;
 include     /etc/nginx/ssl.conf;

 .............

}
```

вот файлы которые были получены при установке используя [гайд](https://kamaok.org.ua/?p=664)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Подскажите что не так? Какие есть у вас предположения?

Comment: Во-первых, это всё-таки не ошибка, а предупреждение. Во-вторых, ssl stapling для самоподписанного сертификата это странно и нелогично, так что ему положено не работать

Comment: Что нужно сделать чтобы он работал корректно?

Comment: Получить нормальный сертификат от любого нормального центра сертификации вместо своего самопального?

Comment: Они ж платные вроде ). А это не есть хорошо)

Comment: Let's Encrypt бесплатный